# How to change the Window Form background color with the selected color from listbox in WPF with using Binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, listbox, wpf-controls

I am using a `ListBox`, and I want to change the background window color when I click the `ListBoxItem`, my method is working but I want to do same thing with binding.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10,20,30,10" Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Blue" Name="lst" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Green" Name="lst1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Yellow" Name="lst2"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Transparent" Name="lst3"/>


        </ListBox>
```

I am using the following method:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       if(listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "0")
       {
            win.Background = Brushes.Blue;
       }
       else if (listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "1")
       {
           win.Background = Brushes.Green;
       }
       else if (listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "2")
       {
           win.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
       }
       else
       {
           win.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
       }


    }
```

But I need to use bind method,How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very easily by following MVVM and making the values of the listbox (essentially colors) come from Model. The background of the form can then be bound to the same values.

So essentially your model will be:

```
public class ColorModel
{
   public Enum Colors{get; set;}
}

public enum Colors
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}
```

Your Viewmodel will make a collection of this.

And then you View will bind it to the listbox. 
For Window Background - you can bind this to the listbox values and using converter (since the model didnt define this as colors) - you can change colors.

If you want a full working sample - let me know - will try to post something shortly when at my desk.

Comment: Please can you post sample,it will be really helpful because I never use binding I want to learn something new.